# Are there any established direct eigensolvers for sparse hermitian matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have experience with LAPACK (direct solvers) and ARPACK (sparse iterative solvers), but are there any sparse direct solvers? I am concerned more with preserving space than with fast solutions. ARPACK is fast when it converges, but seems to struggle when many eigenvalues are degenerate.

Comment: I suggest you provide the details of how you are using arpack. Among other things, it is not clear to me what you mean by direct and iterative "solvers".

Comment: There is a very fine line between direct and iterative in the end. Lapack's eigenvalue algorithms based on QR/Francis iteration are iterative, but so fast and effortless that they 'feel' direct. And even "direct" algorithms to solve linear systems like `DGESVX` include an iterative refinement step.

Comment: ARPACK is implementing $iterative$ solvers. It does not require or assume any sparsity. 

IMHO, a better distinction is whether you need a subset of approximations to the eigenpairs (i.e. < n, the matrix dimension) or a complete set of approximations (i.e. = n, the matrix dimension).

- How many modes do you need?

- If you know the maximum size of degeneracy, then a block implementation of Arnoldi (or Lanczos) could handle the degeneracy.

Comment: @user7440 The number of modes is significantly less than n. Your comment on a block implementation is interesting. Could you expand on that?

Comment: @DJames A reference discussing these aspects is https://doi.org/10.1137/S0895479888151111 
Section 4.5 discusses the block size: "[...] it is best to choose a blocksize as large as the largest expected multiplicity if eigenvalues of moderate multiplicities are expected. This is particularly important if many clusters of eigenvalues are expected (Table 12). A blocksize of 6 or 7 works well in problems with rigid body modes. We rarely find that p > 10 is cost-effective."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There cannot be. The problem of finding eigenvalues is nonlinear, and it can be shown that finding eigenvalues of a matrix is a problem that is equivalent to finding roots of polynomials. We know that the latter only has solutions that can be computed in a finite number of steps for polynomial degree $\le 4$ in general. If there was a direct solver for the eigenproblem, it would also provide a way to find the roots of arbitrary-order polynomials.

In other words, any algorithm to find the eigenvalues of a matrix beyond size 4 must necessarily be iterative.